# Image distortion with sine/cosine

Tags: image-processing, trigonometry, distortion

Is it possible to distort an image using trigonometric functions like **sine** and **cosine** so that it comes out wavy.

If so, how.

**PHP** is the *preferred* language but it can be any...

Comment: you sure seem intent on doing *something* with trig functions. homework maybe?

Comment: EXTREME curiosity... they interest me.

Comment: Possible captcha implementation?

Comment: Color but if it has to black and white that's ok

Comment: What is captcha implementation?

Comment: If you want to learn more how sine and cosine relates to the unit circle you could try drawing a circle with them. If you want to distort an image you could have a go at a polar rippling effect.

Comment: Mark: It's a thing which verifies your humanity; it makes it hard for robots to abuse the site.

Comment: @Mark: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA

Comment: For some of the pixel-level answers here, you could do the same w/ textured geometry, applying the transformations instead to the vertices. If you still want to do pixel level ripples, but only on one axis, you could use blt functions and shift entire slices rather than having to loop through all the pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using phadej's answer I got a solution...

**The picture is this...**

[image]

**The code -**

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('pic.png');
    $newim = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($im),imagesy($im));
    for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($im); $x++) {
        for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($im); $y++) {

        $rgba = imagecolorsforindex($im, imagecolorat($im, $x, $y));
        $col = imagecolorallocate($newim, $rgba["red"], $rgba["green"], $rgba["blue"]);


        $distorted_y = ($y + round(100*sin($x/50)) + imagesy($im)) % imagesy($im);
        imagesetpixel($newim, $x, $distorted_y, $col);
        }
    }

    imagepng($newim);
    ?>
```

**The output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. An image is just a two dimensional array of pixels and it's possible to reorganize them freely. One easy way is to create new image and sample pixels from original image thru some distortion function.

```
$original = read_image_pixels(); // using GD or some other way
for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
  for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
    // we are adding $height and taking modulo
    // to insure that $distorted_y is positive and less then $height.
    $distorted_y = ($y + round(10*sin($x/20)) + $height) % $height;

    $distorted[$x][$y] = $original[$x][$distorted_y];
  }
}
```

Edit: This can be generalized even further. Many familiar effects like blur and unsharpen are convolution filters. They are pretty well explained at [the GameDev article](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/imageproc/page2.asp). We can think the above sin-distortion as a convolution filter with spatially variable kernel (coefficient matrix).

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on how your image works. I don't speak PHP, so this is a general solution.

If we can move individual pixels, the conceptually simplest way to do this would be to say

y<sub>old</sub> = old y-position of a pixel
y<sub>new</sub> = new y-position of the pixel
x = x-position of the pixel
L = length of the image in pixels
N = number of trigonometric cycles to apply (ie number of sin waves)

Then we just iterate through the image. For each value of x, we move the y-pixel:

y<sub>new</sub> = y<sub>old</sub> * (1+sin(N*π*x/L)) / 2